# StringBuilder comparison returns wrong result

Tags: java

When I compare two StringBuilder objects having same underline string, `false` is returned even when value should be true.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        StringBuilder strBld_1 = new StringBuilder("string");
        StringBuilder strBld_2 = new StringBuilder("string");

        System.out.println(strBld_1.equals(strBld_2));
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because `StringBuilder` doesn't override `equals` method from `Object` class.

You will have to convert both `StringBuilder` objects to `String` and then compare them

`System.out.println(strBld_1.toString().equals(strBld_2.toString()));`

This will give you correct result. Obviously, you will have to mind **null** checks etc.

> As per `equals` contract, if equals is overriden then `hashCode` must also be overriden, but as `StringBuffer` is mutable so any change in its value will impact objects hashcode. This might lead to stored values in `HashMap` to be lost if `StringBuilder` is used as keys.

Comment: you may want to add the implication of not overriding equals. good answer, otherwise

Comment: The `CharSequence` interface Javadoc has some verbage about not mandating that `equals` be implemented, too.

Answer (score 3):

The deeper answer here: don't **assume** what equality means for a class. Instead: turn to the javadoc to first determine if that class *overrides* `equals()` - and if so, read about the details there.

In other words: you simply assumed that StringBuilders are *equal* when they have matching content. But that isn't true. Because this class doesn't override `equals()` you only receive a `true` result when doing `someBuilder.equals(someBuilder)`. The chars sent into the builder simply do not matter when comparing builders.